# Is it possible to retrieve the index of a string array? in JAVA

Tags: java

I'm coding a calculator in Java with swing, so i have this array actually
`private String[] array = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ".", "=", "C", "+", "-", "*", "/"};`

this array which i then pass on to my method:

```
      private JPanel init(String[] tab) {
      JPanel c = new JPanel ( new GridLayout( 5,1));
      for (String e : tab) 
      {

        values = new JButton(e);
        values.addActionListener(this);
        c.add(values);
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    return c;
  }
```

The problem is that in my addActionListener I only get the text from my table, so it's great you're going to tell me, but I also need to get the index when I make a click, because I would like to use it for the operators, to differentiate all that.

I'm still looking for a solution, but so far I haven't found it.
Here is the code of my ActionListener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).getText());
    value = ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).getText();
}
```

Comment: `int idx = java.util.Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(value);`

Answer (score 0):

The index of a particular element in an ArrayList can be obtained by using the method java.util.ArrayList.indexOf().

You can see an example here:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/get-the-index-of-a-particular-element-in-an-arraylist-in-java

Answer (score 0):

So far you have the buttons in JPanel all set up now you should do

on your clicked button

```
if(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().equals("*")) 
    //perform multiplication
else if(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().equals("+"))
   // do the addition
and so on ....
```

as you have to check to source of event every time a button is clicked so i recommend using an anonymous inner class as a listener so that you don't have to check the source of event.

do it as `button.setActionListener(e -> {your code here}) // if you know lambdas`

as anonymous inner class

`button.setActionListener(new ActionListener(){
@Override
public void actionPerformed(Action event) { your code here}});`

do this for every button then you will not have to do the button.getSource() hence increased response time on button clicks